# Android Development Deploy to Google Console Failing

Tags: android, upload, bundle, google-play-console

(1) C# Visual Studio development of Android APP
(2) Build release version with SIGNED keystore/certificate
(3) Key store created with KEYTOOL utility

keytool -genkey -alias keyAlias-keyalg RSA
-keypass changeit
-storepass changeit
keystore keystore.jks

(4) Log in to GOOGLE PLAY console --- prepare release
(5) Drag and drop signed Android bundle (.aab) file
(6) Get error:
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again:SHA1: E0:EA:30:94:7B:EB:48:16:5A:89:87:BA:E5:29:C5:5E:E6:A5:60:DF.
(7) No app was successfully uploaded ... using option where Googles manages security key. Totally confusing documentation.

No response from GOOGLE

Comment: Unclear if this is for new or existing app, how big is your app and if you've read: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

Comment: Brand new app. APP bundle is 11.7 MB (12,372,042 bytes), Thanks for the link but my app is quite small. I suspect there is something munged in Googles repository for my key ---- "Google is protecting your app signing key Show more"

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty. No response from Google. Need to delete APP from play console and start again. Not hugely onerous.